# Creating a Discord bot to notify people when to certain text on a website has changed

Tags: discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = '';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online');
})

bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if(msg.content === "?rates"){
        msg.reply('.')
    }
})

bot.login(token);
```

This is what I have so far it is very basic, I understand, I'm just trying to get some sort of idea how to process. What I want is as soon as a website gets updated or changed. I would like it to tag everyone and in a certain channel and specifies what has changed. I know this will be a long process but I'm in for the ride :) would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a webhook on the website and listen to it with your bot, if you have control over the site, [this](https://chatbotslife.com/creating-a-nodejs-based-webhook-for-intelligent-bots-a91ecbe33402) may help you, otherwise you could look if the site has one or perhaps ask an owner.

A probably working but not very nice (and not very clean) solution would be to save the text of the website every 5 seconds or so and compare it to the previous save. If it changed, you notify the members through sending a message.